# Get appwidget position on home screen?

Tags: java, android, widget, rect

I start an activity when a widget icon is clicked.What i want is to send the position of that widget to that activity.I have tried

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("rect", bound);  
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        //intent.putExtra("rect", bound.toString());
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.pic1);

        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.wbutton1, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

in my onUpdate procedure.But this crashes the activity.
I have heard that the position is returned using `intent.getsourceBounds()` .Thats in onReceive ryt?i have tried making bound a global variable.setting its value from onReceive as `bound=intent.getsourceBounds();` That didn't work either.

So my question is
1.How do i get the widget position using `intent.getsourceBounds()` in onUpdate?
2.How can i send it to the activity?

Thank you for your time.

edit:i managed to send string from widget to activity like this:

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("pos", "hello");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

edit 2: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324918/1685829 which says it can be done using getSourceBounds().Can anyone explain how i can use it in onUpdate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to send it; Android does it for you. `getSourceBounds()` can only be used from inside the activity. This information is not available inside `onUpdate()`.